# Can I specify multiple source elements on a HTML5 video element created with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-video

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CrisMVP3200/bxkz8Lsr/) I have created, shows two HTML5 `video` elements, both created by different ways, but both are equal in terms of functionality (both have controls, autoplay when they're ready, play over when they end, and are initially muted).

The first one was created using HTML, and the second one was created using JS.

## HTML5 video element created with HTML

```
<video controls autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" />
</video>
```

## HTML5 video element created with JS

```
function Main() {
    this.video = document.createElement("video");
    this.video.src = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
    this.video.controls = true; 
    this.video.autoplay = true; 
    this.video.loop = true;
    this.video.muted = true
    document.body.appendChild(this.video); /* Append to the body */
}

var main = new Main();
```

My question is concerned to the following: I was looking at this piece of code from [HTML5 Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/), used as an example of how I can **specify multiple source files on a video element** (so, for example, a browser will play a video file depending on the supported formats). In this particular case, two `source` elements are specified.

```
<video controls>
    <source src="devstories.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
    <source src="devstories.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
</video>
```

I know I can add additional sources to a `video` element created with HTML. For example, this video element with two sources, the first one with a OGV file, and the second one with a MP4 file:

```
<video controls autoplay loop muted>
    <source src=".../foo.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
    <source src=".../foo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Can I do the same, but with an HTML5 video element created with JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.

I can use the `createElement()` method to create the `source` elements I want, and append them to the `video` element with the `appendChild()` method.

So, I will modify the JS code in the [original fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CrisMVP3200/bxkz8Lsr/) I had posted, to create a `video` element with JS, that will feature:

- Two sources:

  - OGG file source
  - MP4 file source
- All the functionality defined on the two videos in the original fiddle:

  - Controls
  - Autoplay when it is ready
  - Play over on ending
  - Initially muted

Esentially, an element similar to my `video` element with two sources, created with HTML and defined in the question:

```
<video controls autoplay loop muted>
    <source src=".../foo.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
    <source src=".../foo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

## Modifying the video element

I proceed to modify the `video` element created, discarding the `src` property, but keeping all the rest of the properties I had defined:

```
/* Video element creation */
this.video = document.createElement("video");

/* Video element properties settings */ 
this.video.controls = true;
this.video.autoplay = true;
this.video.loop = true;
this.video.muted = true;
```

## Creating the source elements and appending them to the video element

To add a source, I create a `source` element with the `createElement()` method, later I set the attributes that source will have, and finally I use the method `appendChild()` to append the source element to the `video` element. Here, I create the source element for the OGV file.

```
/* First source element creation */
this.source1 = document.createElement("source");

/* Attribute settings for my first source */
this.source1.setAttribute("src", ".../foo.ogv");
this.source1.setAttribute("type", "video/ogg");

/* Append the first source element to the video element */
this.video.appendChild(this.source1);
```

I can add more than one source, so for this question, as I wanted to add two sources, a OGV file and a MP4 file, I will add both. I proceed to create the `source` element for the second one.

```
/* Second source element creation */
this.source2 = document.createElement("source");

/* Attribute settings for my second source */
this.source2.setAttribute("src", ".../foo.mp4");
this.source2.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");

/* Append the second source element to the video element */
this.video.appendChild(this.source2);
```

## Appending the video element to the body

As I finished to add the sources elements to my `video` element, the only thing left to do, is to append the video element to the HTML body with `appendChild()`:

```
document.body.appendChild(this.video);
```

## Final code

For the answering code, I will put first the `video` element with two sources, created with HTML and defined in the question, for comparison purposes. I added a `<hr>` break, just for aesthetic reasons.

### HTML (Body)

```
<video controls autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<hr/>

<!-- 
    As the video element created with JS is appended to the body, 
    it will be located here, at the end of that body.
 -->
```

### JavaScript

```
function Main() {
    this.video = document.createElement("video");
    this.video.controls = true;
    this.video.autoplay = true;
    this.video.loop = true;
    this.video.muted = true;

    this.source1 = document.createElement("source");
    this.source1.setAttribute("src", 
                              "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv");
    this.source1.setAttribute("type", "video/ogg");
    this.video.appendChild(this.source1);

    this.source2 = document.createElement("source");
    this.source2.setAttribute("src", 
                              "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
    this.source2.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");
    this.video.appendChild(this.source2);

    document.body.appendChild(this.video);
}

var main = new Main();
```

## Fiddle

In [this new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CrisMVP3200/f443dyr1/) you can see all the code in action.

Comment: Why ask a question and then answer it yourself? maybe you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hmmm. This very lengthy answer was posted within the same minute that the question was asked. Seems like a comment with a link to the original source would have been appropriate.

Comment: I included the answer with the question. Both were submitted together marking the "Answer your own question" checkbox.